# Simple strip in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a really simple of way stripping content from this string:

**Example:**

```
/m/NEEDED/
```

I would like to strip everything except "NEEDED".

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Is it always in that form, `/` followed by `content` followed by `/` followed by `wanted content` followed by `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "/m/NEEDED/";
$newStr = preg_replace("~(/m/|/)~", "", $str);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/909fd.php)

**OR**

```
$str = "/m/NEEDED/";
$newStr = preg_replace("|/(.*?)/(.*?)/|", "$2", $str);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/31abf.php)

**OR**

```
$str = "/m/NEEDED/";
$newStr = str_replace(array('/', 'm'), "", $str);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/9c928.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `str_replace()` one is quite specific, and the one I'd use.

But since you mentioned `strip()`, it reminded me of `trim()`:

```
echo trim('/m/NEEDED/','/m');
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AcDZCM

Comment: What about the leading forward slash?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $strip = array("/","m");
   echo str_replace($strip,"","text input here");
?>
```

Add more characters that you want to strip in the array if you want.